# How to configure Cordova app to be registered in the "share to" apps

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, android-intent, share

The goal here is to be able to share a picture (from the Gallery app, for example) to my app.  In other words, pushing the share button in the Gallery app should result in my app appearing among the list of possible recipients of the image.

If I understand properly, the word is "intent".  Various sources claim that adding intent configs to AndroidManifest.xml and/or config.xml should enable this, but so far everything I've tried has no exactly no impact.

For example, following https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/101/how-to-list-your-cordova-app-in-open-with-menu-in-android-and-handle-the-intent-event has no effect.

Here is my latest attempt:

config.xml

```
<widget 
    name="Spoticle"
    id="com.spoticle" 
    version="` + version + `" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

and AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="./application/activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
            <data android:scheme="file" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I just removed `android:pathPattern` and `android:scheme` from `<intent-filter>` and it worked for me.

```xml
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
```